# Why my textbox shows ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm building rails application and I use `form_for` to render the form. Everything works fine works fine except one text field has `ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy` inside the text which I'm not sure where it's coming from.

Here's my form

```
<%= form_for(@video, html: { class: "directUpload" }, multipart: true) do |f| %>
  <% if @video.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@video.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @video.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :path %><br>
    <%= f.file_field :path%>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :tags %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :tags %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And here's my `Video` model

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :video_tags
  has_many :tags, through: :video_tags
end
```

Here's the screenshot[image]

Comment: f.text_field only works for single objects, like title and path. tags is a collection, so you have to use something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple tags that you want show in form. Your controller could serve all tags for form where you could show them with http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_from_collection_for_select for example.