# How to get ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy value for form item

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, activerecord

I'm trying to access values in a form that is connected to the parent with a has_many relationship. Everything comes out great except the field is filled with:

`#<Client::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007f800f2a6408>`

In this case there are 2 clients attached and both fields print successfully, but both are filled with the text above (but with different numbers after the colon which I assume is their object ID)

This is the relevant code for the form:

```
<% @deal.clients.each do |client| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :client %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :clients %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This is the model if it's helpful for background:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :deals
...
class Deal < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :clients
end
...
class Client < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :deal
end
```

How do I get the name in the form?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29504020/why-my-textbox-shows-activerecord-associations-collectionproxy-in-form) has a similar form and output, but the models are different and I don't need multiple names in the same field since I'm iterating over each one.

One last thing, if it's useful, here is the client schema:

```
create_table "clients", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "deal_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["deal_id"], name: "index_clients_on_deal_id"
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better way to do this (in this particular case) is to use [Rails nested forms](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#building-complex-forms). The original way of setting up the form (with the addendum in comment) will get the name value in the correct box, but it won't be possible to change it on submit.

First the model needs to be updated to accept nested attributes

```
class Deal < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :clients
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :clients
end
```

Then whitelist the client attributes in the Deal controller

```
def deal_params
    params.require(:deal).permit(:headline, :matter, :summary, clients_attributes: [:id, :name])
end
```

and finally update the form to remove the each loop and use `fields_for` instead

```
<%= f.fields_for :clients do |client_form| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= client_form.label :client %><br />
    <%= client_form.text_field :name %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

It's not necessary to loop through each client because `fields_for` will do this by default.

Answer (score 1):

What data do yo want to display in the form?

At the moment when you call:

```
<%= f.text_field :clients %>
```

You're creating a field in the form for an attribute called 'clients', which neither model has. This is already a form for an individual client, so we'll need their attributes in here:

```
<% @deal.clients.each do |client| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :client_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Assuming you want the form to display the name of the client then this should work for you.

EDIT: I don't think I explained, you're seeing:

```
#<Client::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007f800f2a6408>
```

Because you call f.clients, which returns the active record association of every client associated with the deal. If you had done clients.each do |client| and then f.client, you would receive just the object, which would look similar to above. What you want to do is access the attribute of the object you want, so f.client.name, or just f.name as we're already dealing with a client in the form.

Comment: Thank you, this pointed me in the right direction! I was able to fix it by adding `<%= f.text_field :clients, :value => client.name %>`